# How do I remove the "Windows XP Professional setup" partition from my hard drive?

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

I've been given a Dell PC and when I boot it up it asks which OS I want to run:

- Windows XP Home
- Windows XP Professional setup

It looks like someone has started to install XP Professional on the same partition but didn't go through with it. Is there a way I can remove XP Professional so that XP Home boots automatically as it should?

Answer (score 6):

[Open Msconfig](http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/index.html), go to the BOOT.INI Tab, click the "Check All Boot Paths" button to clean up the invalid entry.

.

[image]

Comment: GAAAAH. I knew it was under System Configuration but I coudln't remember that it was "msconfig" to get to it. +1 to you sir.

Comment: Well nice to actually add a picture!